# convert string Time to Time Object Java "Text could not be parsed at index 0"

Tags: java, time

I have the following String Format "0 hours : 5 mins : 21 secs".
I need to convert into the format: "hh:mm:ss", So i would be able to calculate the sum of total hours in a list.

I am using the following

```
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh 'hours' : mm 'mins' : ss 'secs'", Locale.US);
        LocalDate odt = LocalDate.parse(k, parser);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        String printDate = formatter.format(odt);
        System.out.println(printDate);
```

But It gives me an error : "Text '0 hours : 5 mins : 321 secs' could not be parsed at index 0".

This mistake happens on line: LocalDate odt = LocalDate.parse(k, parser);

Comment: Why is it 312 seconds (when that is greater than 60)?

Comment: Sorry, There was a typo. It suppose to be 21. But the problem still persist tho.

Comment: Please update the question to show 21.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You needed to use a `LocalTime` instead of a `LocalDate`, and your input format had errors.

Here are my test results.

```
00:05:43
02:25:31
01:06:14
04:43:57
```

Here's the runnable example code I used.  Thanks to @DevilsHnd for the input `String` array.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DurationConve3rsion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] stringTimes = { "0 hours : 5 mins : 43 secs", 
                "2 hours : 25 mins : 31 secs",
                "1 hours : 06 mins : 14 secs", 
                "4 hours : 43 mins : 57 secs" };

        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "H 'hours :' m 'mins :' s 'secs'", Locale.US);

        for (String k : stringTimes) {
            LocalTime odt = LocalTime.parse(k, parser);

            DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
            String printDate = formatter.format(odt);
            System.out.println(printDate);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string like that then perhaps it's just easier to create your own parser:

```
int totalHours = 0;

// Demo time Strings         
String[] stringTimes = {"0 hours : 5 mins : 43 secs",
                        "2 hours : 25 mins : 31 secs",
                        "1 hours : 06 mins : 14 secs",
                        "4 hours : 43 mins : 57 secs"};

// Iterate through all the demo time strings contained in array.    
for (String strgTime : stringTimes) {
    /* Parse the current time string into hour, minutes, seconds 
       (Letter case is ignored).    */
    String[] timeParts = strgTime.trim().split("(?i)\\s+hours\\s+:\\s+|\\s+mins\\s+:\\s+|\\s+secs\\s+");

    /* Validate the fact that the split element at index 0 of
       timeParts[] which is to hold hours is indeed a string 
       representation of a Integer value.           */
    if (timeParts[0].matches("\\d+")) {
       /* Yes, It is a string representation of a Integer value.
          Convert this String value to Integer type and add it 
          to totalHours.  */
        totalHours += Integer.valueOf(timeParts[0]);
    }
}

// Display Total Hours in console
System.out.println("Total Hours:\t" + totalHours + " Hours");
```

After running this you should see in the Console Window:  `Total Hours: 7 Hours`. If you remove the comments and the demo string times array, you can see it really isn't very much code.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time.Duration for an amount of time

I take it that `0 hours : 5 mins : 312 secs` is an amount of time (equal to 10 minutes 12 seconds or a total of 612 seconds). It’s not a time of day. If so, the correct class to use is `Duration`. (`LocalTime` is for at time of day such as 00:10:12 when this signifies 10 minutes 12 seconds past midnight.)

Unfortunately java.time doesn’t include any mechanism for parsing arbitrary duration strings. The `Duration` class can parse duration strings in ISO 8601 format, and that’s it. Fortunately, for most formats it’s manageable to convert the duration string that you’ve got into ISO 8601 using a regular expression. This is so in your case too.

ISO 8601 format for durations is a bit peculiar until you get used to it. It goes like `PT0H5M312S`. Think of it as *a period of time of 0 hours 5 minutes 312 seconds*.

```
    String amountOfTimeAsString = "0 hours : 5 mins : 312 secs";
    String iso8601String = "PT" +  amountOfTimeAsString.replaceAll(
            "(\\d+)\\s*(h)ours?\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*(m)ins?\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*(s)ecs?",
            "$1$2$3$4$5$6");
    Duration dur = Duration.parse(iso8601String);
    System.out.println(dur);
```

Output is in ISO 8601 format too:

> PT10M12S

A period of time of 10 minutes 12 seconds.

A `Duration` has a `plus` method for adding durations together. It sounds like what you need for summing them up. For getting the hours out of the sum use the `toHours` method.